rqt error in ROS2 Tutorial
I have started working through the ROS2 Tutorials:
Using turtlesim, ros2, and rqt
When I first execute rqt I get the following error messages:
kmu69@nU-Boats:~$ rqt
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()

Try login with X11 instead of the default Wayland.
